# SeekBar Android with popup indicator

Tags: android, popup, seekbar, indicator

How to make SeekBar with popup indicator
[like this](https://plus.google.com/u/2/102817709334054900562/posts/Nh8xNdYSWaJ?pid=6146332944166044098&oid=102817709334054900562)

Comment: use a custom thumb drawable: just make a class that extends `Drawable` and implement `draw(Canvas)` method

Answer (score 1):

you can try this library, support pre-lollipop  https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar